# Getting new location from android is not working

Tags: android

**What I am trying to do:**
i am trying to to get the fresh new co=ordinates from user(not last known location)

**What is happening:**

- I am not able to get the new location
- I also cannot see the toast being fired

***In on create i have the code***

```
LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0,mLocationListener);
```

***I have a inner class***

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            //your code here
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
            longitude=location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HURRAY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

### {EDIT}

```
LocationManager LM = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            //your code here
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
            longitude=location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HURRAY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    LM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    //LM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    Location lastLocation = LM.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: are you want location from NETWORK_PROVIDER or frm GPS?

Comment: if you want accurate location do use GPS like this. mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0.0f, locationListener);

Comment: Surely you have declared <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />...?

Comment: Please check the update ... also i have added the proper permissions in manifest (Edit code is in oncreate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add OnResume method.
Try this:

```
@Override
     protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, (long)0.1, (float)0.1, this);
     }
```

**EDIT:**
look how I implemented my app, it works fine.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon= location.getLongitude();

        updateCamera(lat,lon);    
    }   

    @Override
     protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, (long)0.001, (float)0.001, this);
     }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**And that code in onCreate**

```
this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
        //or getBestProvider(criteria, false), but network is better not to jump location.
        provider = locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;//getBestProvider(crit,true); 
        //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Comment: OnCreate method is called once when the activity is created, while onResume doesn`t, so try, I hope it will help you

Comment: I am sorry but this answer is wrong. Requesting location updates in the onCreate definitely works - it is just a matter of your strategy when you want to have location updates and when you want to stop them.

Comment: it extends FragmentActivity and implements LocationListener,
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{}

Comment: Yes your code is working .... Thanks ... In my implementation i call it in oncreate .... also is it possible to call this only once because its keeps on firing ...... i could increase the time but i just want to call it only once !

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct permissions in your Manifest (Coarse location in case you go with the network provider).
I would also advice to also add the GPS provider as network is not very reliable - depending on your requirements of course.
And finally debugging via Toast is not the best option I would recommend to simply set a breakpoint in your Eclipse and fire up your emulator.

Comment: Please check the update ... also i have added the proper permissions in manifest (Edit code is in oncreate) ... even i checked with breakpoint ... control never comes there

Answer (score 0):

@user3690518 in fact, you don't nescessarily add OnResume method. I have an application which works correctly with just :

```
LocationManager LM = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    LM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, ll);
    Location lastLocation = LM
            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

placed into OnCreate function. I think he never had location initialized so OnLocationChanged never has been called

Comment: Please check the update ... also i have added the proper permissions in manifest (Edit code is in oncreate)